# Error in PHP file uploading

Tags: php

Now, I am getting another problem. I am trying to upload file with this code :-

```
<form action="up.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="200000" />
    Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload!"/>  
</form>
```

Here is the up.php:-

```
if(!isset($_FILES["uploadedfile"])) die("No file found");
```

In the above code, it says "No file found". why isn't it having the file?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form.

```
<form action="up.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: wow.. it worked... but what's the use of the enctype thing... and what does it mean? Thanks :)

Comment: It's require to send encoded data from form. You can have detail information [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2)

Answer (score 2):

Add **enctype="multipart/form-data"** to form tag

```
<form action="up.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="200000" />
  Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" /><br />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload!"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add enctype in your `form tag`.

```
<form action="up.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```